# Limit on the number of equality filters in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am planning to create a follow system, where a user can follow multiple users. For my purpose I expect a user to follow around 20-25 users.

So for creating the feed, I am planning to create a dynamic field in the post whose key is uid of user creating post like following.

```
{
postText : "random text",
postImage : 'some url',
{userUID} : true
}
```

Here userUID is the uid of user creating post. So this way I can create a query like:

```
db.collection('posts')
  .where(useruid1, '==', true)
  .where(useruid2, '==', true)
  .where(useruid1, '==', true)
  .where(useruid3, '==', true)
```

where `useruid1`, `useruid2`, `useruid3` are users that I follow.

So I need to know if there is any limit on the number of equality filters in where query. Also, will more filters affect the performance??

I couldn't find it in the docs. Sorry if I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you'll need an 'OR' or 'IN' query vs a series of ANDs (i.e. you want to return a result if it is any of the users the user has subscribed to). For that case, you need to create multiple queries/listeners. Here's a small example of that

```
// the posts returned from the queries
const posts = new Map();

// array to unsubscribe from listening to firestore
let postUnsubscribe = [];

// function to subscribe to all user posts
const subscribeToPosts = () => {
  usersToFollow = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"];

  postUnsubscribe = usersToFollow.map(userToFollow => {
    return firestore
      .collection("posts")
      .where("useruid", "==", userToFollow)
      .onSnapshot(handlePost);
  });
};

// handles updates to post (for all the users)
const handlePost = querySnapshot => {
  for (let change of querySnapshot.docChanges) {
    if (change.type === "added" || change.type === "modified") {
      posts.set(change.doc.id, change.doc.data());
    } else if (change.type === "removed") {
      posts.delete(change.doc.id);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I realize that my query won't work because the query filters are like AND not OR. Also, as far as I know, firestore security rules are like all or nothing. They won't filter the result based on the access. If that's what you are proposing.

Comment: Updated above to show how to do multiple OR type queries in firestore. On the security rule side, I'll try to find some time to elaborate more, but Firestore security rules do enable looking up permissions in a different table and checking if things are in them (i.e. you can see if the user is following).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The above solution is what I have implemented. The only thing is pagination gets a little ugly with this. Right now what I am doing is get posts by the users in a way you showed above for previous two days, then next query for the two days before that and so on. It works fine, except for redundant queries and not knowing where to stop if there is no result (I want to  implement infinite scroll). There might be some more results few days ago for some users and for some there might not be. So I am exploring other options. I will read more into role-based access

Comment: Np. Added a tiny example of the security rules example above.

Re: pagination on variant 1, I don't have a great answer on that. I would recommend first querying the results for the next x results, and, if that doesn't contain it, then go to cloudstore.

Comment: Did some more testing on the security rules side, and that won't work. ;-) I've removed it.

Comment: Well, a working solution for such use case is going to be ugly with firestore I suppose. Thanks for your time.